# Need to remove *.xml from unknown directories that are older than x days

Tags: bash, shell

We have a directory:

/home/httpdocs/

In this directory there may be directories or sub directories of directories, or sub directories of sub directories, and so on and so forth that contain XML files (files that end in .xml) - We do not know which direcrtory contains xml files and these directories contain a massive amount of files

we want to archive all files and remove them from the actual directories so that we only contain the last 7 days worth of xml files in the above mentioned directories.

It was mentioned to me that logrotate would be a good option to do this in, is that the best way to do it, and if so - how would we set it up?

Also if not using lot rotate can this be scripted? Can this script be run during production hours or will it bog down the system?

Sas

Answer (score 3):

```
find -name "*.xml" -mtime +7 -print0 | tar -cvzf yourArchive.tar.gz --remove-files --null --files-from -
```

Will create a gzip compressed tar file 'yourArchive.tar.gz', containing all *.xml files in the current directory and any depth of subdirectory that was not changed during the last 24*7 hours and after adding these files to the tar archive the files are deleted.

Edit:

> Can this script be run during production hours or will it bog down the
>   system?

Depends on your system actually. This does create lots of I/O load. If your production system uses a lot of I/O and you don't happen to have a fantastic I/O subsystem (like a huge raid system connected using fibre channel or the like), then this will have some noticable impact on your performance. How bad this is depends on more details though.

If system load is an issue than you could create a small database that keeps track of the files, maybe using inotify, which can run in background over a larger period of time, beeing less noticed.

You can also try to set the priority of the mentioned processes using `renice`, but since the problem is I/O and not CPU (unless your CPU sucks and your I/O is really great for some reason), this might not lead to the desired effect. But then the next best option would be to write your own script crawling the file tree that is decorated with sleeps. It will take some time to complete but will generate less impact on your production system. I would not recommend any of this unless you really have pressure to act.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find /home/httpdocs -name "*.xml" -mtime +7 -exec archive {} \;` where `archive` is a program that archives and removes an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

It'll probably be easiest to do this with `find` and a cron job.

The find command:

```
find /home/httpdocs -name \*.xml -ctime +7 -exec mv -b -t /path/to/backup/folder {} +
```

This will move any file ending in .xml within the /home/httpdocs tree to the backup folder you provide, making a backup of any file that would be overwritten (`-b`).

Now, to set this up as a cron job, run `crontab -e` as a user who has write permissions on both the httpdocs and backup folders (probably root, so `sudo crontab -e`). Then add a line like the following:

```
14    3    *    *    *  find /home/httpdocs -name \*.xml -ctime +7 -exec mv -b -t /path/to/backup/folder {} +
```

This will run the command at 3:14am every day (change the 3 and 14 for different times). You could also put the `find` command into a script and run that, just to make the line shorter.